# How do I pass user profile pic in nav through AppServiceProvider? laravel-5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, service-provider

This is a very common task. I'm trying to display user profile pic on the nav throughout the site.
The profile pictures are urls from google,facebook,or from s3 if user uploads them.  I have this function to access the pictures

```
public static function get_profile_pic($user){
    $pic=array_flatten($user->media->where('category','profile'))[0]->path;
    if(empty($pic)){
        $pic = '/images/user-icon.jpg';
        return $pic;
    }else 
        return $pic;
}
```

In my nav view I have :

```
@if(Auth::check())                  
<li><img class='nav-pic' src='<?php link_to_action('HomeController@index',$pic)?>'/></li>
```

my homecontroller:

class HomeController extends Controller {

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    if ($request->user()) {
        $user = $request->user();
        $pic = User::get_profile_pic($user);
 }
    view()->share('scripts', array('home.js'));
    return view('home.index', compact('user'));
}
```

and this is what I have in the AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    if (Auth::check()){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $pic = User::get_profile_pic($user);
        view()->composer('includes.new_nav1',function($view){
            $view->with('pic', User::get_profile_pic($user));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed a tutorial in laracast somewhat.  https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25.

Comment: change `$view->with('pic', User::get_profile_pic($user));` to `$view->with('pic',$pic);` and I take it you have `use App\User;` at the top of your AppServiceProvider class if not either add it in or change `$pic = User::....` to `$pic = App\User::..`

Comment: Also does your static function live in your User model? you are calling it on the user model and then passing the user to it? should it not be just `$pic = get_profile_pic($user);` ? I would have this sort of thing as a helper function autoloaded via composer

Comment: Yeah its in my User Model.  My fellow developers don't want anything model related as a helper function, so I didn't what else to do.  Also I'm still getting undefined variable pic message.  Am i perhaps passing the wrong thing in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you see something like `User::method($user)` it's probably better to refactor that so that the method is on the user object itself, i.e. `$user->method()`

Laravel has something even better called an "appended" attribute. That means it behaves exactly like a normal attribute (database column), you just have to define an accessor method for it:

---

1 - Take your function:

```
public static function get_profile_pic($user)
```

and change it to

```
public function getProfilePicAttribute()
```

2 - Replace `$user` with `$this` inside of that method.

3 - Finally, add this array to your User model:

```
protected $appends = ['profile_pic'];
```

This tells Laravel that "profile_pic" behaves like a database attribute but should **not** be saved into the database table.

Now for any `User` object, you can simply use `$user->profile_pic`, e.g.

```
<img src="{{ $user->profile_pic }}">
```

And change your view composer to just `view->with($user, Auth::user())`

Comment: This is really darn cool... Thanks.  I can think of a fews i can use this in my app :)